# Doubt with improper integral

Tags: analysis, improper-integrals

I have to study the convergence of the improper integral
$$\int_0^1 \frac{\sin(\sqrt{x})}{x(x-1)(\sqrt{x+2})}dx$$
So I split it
$$\int_0^a \frac{\sin(\sqrt{x})}{x(x-1)(\sqrt{x+2})}dx + \int_a^1 \frac{\sin(\sqrt{x})}{x(x-1)(\sqrt{x+2})}dx$$
the first is asymptotic to
$$\frac{\sqrt{x}}{x}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}} $$
that converges.
The second is asymptotic to
$$\frac{\sin{1}}{(x-1)(\sqrt{2})} $$
that diverges. So the integral diverges, is that correct?

Comment: Yes. And no. It's not $\sqrt{2}$ in the denominator. But apart from that it's correct.

Comment: Sure is $\sqrt{3}$, my bad